# SQL Server Management Studio 64 bit installation problem

Tags: sql-server, 64-bit

I was running this fine on my current laptop but it was the 32 bit version. I recently upgraded Office to 64 bit and as part of this process I had to uninstall all 32 bit Microsoft products, including SQL Server.

Now Office 64 bit is working fine but I cannot reinstall SQL Server 64 bit. When I run the exe it flashes up with a small dialogue window that closes immediately, too fast for me to read, I have tried running as administrator with no change.

My add/remove programs has this, any relevance?

[image]

When I try to remove the SQL Server Setup I get this:

[image]

None of the items listed are in my list of installed programs.

Tried the usual rebooting, running when nothing else is open etc.

Comment: How about removing that redistributable? its on 32 bit

Comment: @Mr.J - can't remove it - have edited the question with screenshot of the error.

Comment: how about running the installer as administrator? Is PC reformat an option?

Comment: Tried running as admin, doesn't make any difference, reformat would be a last resort, would want to try other options first.

Comment: Removing everything that is named SQL Server? I'm thinking that this might be a problem with registry...

Comment: Yes that was my thoughts - had a look at the registry but don't want to go deleting stuff out of there without knowing exactly what I am doing.

Comment: I found this, may give it a go:  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5ca393bd-7542-4111-bdb5-83037c31094c/how-do-i-clean-sql-from-the-registry?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade